# How to route I/O to console AND logfile using clipspy

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

I am using [clipspy v1.0.0](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS.

I am trying to get commands from CLIPS rules (e.g. `print t 'WARN: Listen up, maggots...'`) to print to the console by calling my registered function, which will then parse the message and recognise that it is a warning, so use the logging module to write a warning level message to the log file.

This is what I have so far:

#### CLIPS rule file (example.clp)

```
(defrule welcome
(name "Tyler Durden") 
=>
(printout t "INFO: Gentlemen, welcome to Fight Club. The first rule of Fight Club is: you do not talk about Fight Club!" crlf))
```

#### Python program (example.py)

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import re

import clips

log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=log_format)
logger = logging.getLogger('CLIPS') 
log_level  = logging.INFO     
log_filename = 'expert'

handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(f"{log_filename}.log", when="midnight", interval=1)
handler.setLevel(log_level)
formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add a suffix which you want
handler.suffix = "%Y%m%d"

#need to change the extMatch variable to match the suffix for it
handler.extMatch = re.compile(r"^\d{8}$") 

# finally add handler to logger    
logger.addHandler(handler)


def my_print(msg):
    # Placeholder code, not parsing message or using logger for now ...
    print(f"CLIPS: {msg}")


try:

    env = clips.Environment()
    router = clips.LoggingRouter()
    env.add_router(router)
    env.define_function(my_print)
    env.load("example1.clp")
    env.assert_string('(name "Tyler Durden")')
    #env.reset()

    env.run()

    # while True:
    #     env.run()
except clips.CLIPSError as err:
    print(f"CLIPS error: {err}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping...")
finally:
    env.clear()
```

#### Bash

```
me@yourbox$ python example.py 
2023-02-21 23:58:20,860 - INFO - INFO: Gentlemen, welcome to Fight Club. The first rule of Fight Club is: you do not talk about Fight Club!
```

A log file is created, but nothing is written to it. Also, it seems stdout is being simply routed to Pythons stdout, instead of calling my function.

How do I fix the code above, so that when a `(print t)` statement is encountered in a CLIPS program, it, it simultaneously prints to console, and writes to log using the correct (i.e. specified) log level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clips.LoggingRouter` uses the root logger API such as [`logging.info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.info). So, do like the following example.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import clips

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers = [
        logging.StreamHandler(),
        logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('expert.log'),
])

env = clips.Environment()
env.add_router(clips.LoggingRouter())
...
env.run()
```

If you want to specify different log levels for handlers, do like the following example.

```
...
handler1 = logging.StreamHandler()
handler1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler2 = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('expert.log')
handler2.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers = [handler1, handler2])
```

If you want to log a message with the log level determined by the prefix of the message, define a subclass of the `clips.LoggingRouter` instead of hacking the `logging` module, like the following example.

```
...
class LoggingRouterWithLevelByPrefix(clips.LoggingRouter):
    def write(self, name, msg):
        if msg.startswith('WARN:'):
            logging.warn(msg[5:])
        elif msg.startswith('ERROR:'):
            logging.error(msg[6:])
        else:
            logging.info(msg)
...
env.add_router(LoggingRouterWithLevelByPrefix())
...
```

But keep in mind that Clips defines logical names such as `stdout`, `stderr`, `stdwrn`, which `clips.LoggingRouter` uses to determine the log level. So you can use them like the following example.

```
(printout t "This will be the INFO level." crlf)
(printout stdwrn "This will be the WARNING level." crlf)
(printout stderr "This will be the ERROR level." crlf)
```

Comment: +1 Close. I have two gripes **1**. All messages are being logged at the info level (which defeats a major benefit of log files). I want to be able to able to specify the log level of the message in my CLIPS `print t` statement. One way I thought of doing that was to prefix my message with the debug level (e.g. `'WARN: Blah blah'`), and then have a function parse that message and issue the appropriate log write command. **2**. It is not clear how I can set up my handler the way I was doing before.

Comment: Regarding the second gripe, I think I can simply setup the handler up before passing it ... it's almost 3:30 AM, so I'm not thinking clearly, I'll review after I've had some sleep.

Comment: I added other examples. Check them.

Comment: Deriving from `clips.LoggingRouter` was how I was intending to proceed last night, after looking at the clipspy source. However, the solution you proposed (specifying the router name with the ``print` function, seems more simple, and more elegant. The only problem is that `(printout stderr "This will be the ERROR level." crlf)` neither prints to console, or writes to file. I will check to see if that router's priority is being overriden or something more malevolent is going on.

Comment: It was fixed in the master branch for [this issue](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy/issues/48). Try the master branch.

Comment: I'm installing from master branch (as you suggested - to fix the **INFO** log level issue), using `pip install git+https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy.git`, and the build fails with error message: `fatal error: clips.h: No such file or directory`. Do I need to have the CLIPS sources locally (if yes, which version are you binding to? I'm guessing 6.4.0 from the repo tags).  I am installing on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy#building-from-sources) and [this](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#building-from-sources). Run commands in a proper python environment(which provides ```python``` as python3 in a PATH such as python-is-python3 package or Anaconda).

Comment: thanks, but instructions weren't too useful - I eventually had to hack around, to figure out that I had to build wheels locally first, before doing a `pip` local install using the wheel.

Comment: You don't need to build a wheel. You only need to run ```make``` and ```sudo make install```. Building a wheel is needed if you want to distribute the package. For that see [this](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel). But it's not an easy task.

Comment: Clipspy doesn't use a build system such as cibuildwheel or multibuild. See [this](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#manylinux-wheels).